# SQL return lowest value among partition, but if goes negative, stop at first negative value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query where I am calculating a running total using SUM(QTY) OVER (PARTITION BY PART) AS RT. This is working great, but am stuck on the next step. I would like to return the lowest value row encountered but stop at the first negative if one is present. Here is an example screenshot. Ack!

[image]

Comment: It seems like the `over()` clause of the window function is missing an `order by` clause. Please show us your entire query. Seeing the sample data against which the query runs might also be useful.

Comment: Hello GMB - you are correct, my query has an order by date. i left off, thought wasn't relevant to the problem. the dates in the above screenshot would only be pertinent in part C and D, they progress to the future for each row & part.

Comment: @Nicho247 . . . "first negative" suggests that there is a column that specifies the ordering.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets, so ordering has to be encoded in a column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . the specification of "first" suggests that there is an ordering to the rows.  Let me assume there is one using some ordering column.

Then you can use windowing functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             first_value(<ordering col>) over (partition by part order by rt) as oc_at_min_rt,
             min(case when rt < 0 then <ordering col> end) over (partition by part) as first_neg_rt
      from t
     ) t
where order_col = first_neg_rt or
      (first_neg_rt is null and order_col = oc_at_min_rt)
```

Comment: Gordon sir, this is some black magic! You were right about the order by DATE. Sorry for the delay, had to QC the results. The only thing your query was missing was a simple distinct at the top level. Though, you wouldn't have known that from the brief description of my query.

Answer (score 1):

The following unions the lowest positive value and the highest negative value and the selects the minimum in the end.

```
with unions as
(
select part, rt  
from results tb1
 where rt = (select min(rt)
          from results tb2
          where tb2.part = tb1.part
           and tb2.rt > 0)
union
select part, rt
from results tb1
 where rt = (select max(rt)
          from results tb2
          where tb2.part = tb1.part
           and tb2.rt < 0)    
  )
select part, min(rt) want
from unions
group by part;
```

Tested with your data recreated as follows in a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/34446d/10):

```
CREATE TABLE results (
  Part VARCHAR(1),
  RT INTEGER,
  Want VARCHAR(6)
);

INSERT INTO results
  (Part, RT, Want)
VALUES
  ('A', '16', 'return'),
  ('B', '2327', 'return'),
  ('C', '0', ''),
  ('C', '-25', 'return'),
  ('D', '150', ''),
  ('D', '65', ''),
  ('D', '-54', 'return'),
  ('D', '-500', '');
```

Comment: Hi Lars - I have marked the other submission as the solution, however I did try to test your post in good faith. I agree the principle it should work with how you have broken it down. I like it and it is a little more straight forward to see what is going on. However, I think there was an error or two in your code. I changed 'and rt = to' read 'where rt = ' and this got around one error. The other error is the last two lines, it won't allow the subquery 'union' to be called in the where clause. I tried a few alternatives but still couldn't get around it. Thank you though for the effort.

Comment: @Nicho247: I have corrected the mistakes now and tested it in a Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/34446d/10